# Unexpected value for finding parity of a number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, parity

The following code is from Elements of Programming Interview on how to find the parity of a number.

The parity of a number should be 1 if there odd number of 1s in the number. Otherwise, it should be 0.

1011 should return 1

But, the code from the book gives 0 for 1011. What am I missing?

```
public static short parityBitByBitSmart(long x) {
    short result = 0;

    while(x != 0) {
        result ^= 1;
        x &= (x -1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And, I found another code sample with the same unexpected result

```
public static short parityBitByBit(long x) {
    short result = 0;

    while(x != 0) {
        result ^= (x & 1);
        x >>>= 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is it ignoring the sign bit?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the parity of a number".  Parity can be defined to be odd or even, i.e. the bit is added to make the number of `1` bits odd or even, depending on the parity scheme in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1011` (decimal) is `0b1111110011` (binary). And, *that* has an **even** number of `1` bits.